# (iOS) Using UIGestureRecognizer to zoom and pan around a view

Tags: ios, zooming, uipangesturerecognizer, panning, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to perform zooming and panning similar to the UIScrollView by using UIGestures.

My view is drawn from a matrix of ON/OFF cells and needs to be able to support thousands of cells. The drawRect: method takes care of translating the matrix coordinates to screen coordinates. The view has a property for the zoom amount and a CGPoint which holds the offset.

I think if I can figure out the zooming and panning of the following, I should be good. Sorry for the wall of code below, but it represents a complete implementation which mirrors my more complex program.

Right now, the zoom does scale everything, but it needs a way to center itself, just like the UIScrollView zooming does.

The panning just does not work right at all.

#### ZoomView.h

ZoomView takes care of drawing the matrix of bools.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ZoomModel.h"

@interface ZoomView : UIView
{
    ZoomModel *m;
}
@property (nonatomic) float zoomScale;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint offset;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
           andModel:(ZoomModel *)model;

- (BOOL)checkCellAt:(float)x
               andY:(float)y;

- (CGSize)resize;

@end
```

#### ZoomView.m

The drawRect: method does the calculations for determining which matrix element should is in the visible portion of the screen. The visible portion of the screen is determined by the zoomScale and the offset.

```
#import "ZoomView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation ZoomView
@synthesize zoomScale, offset, holdZoom;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
           andModel:(ZoomModel *)model
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        m = model;
        zoomScale = 1.0;
        offset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setZoomScale:(float)s
{
    zoomScale *= s;
    if (zoomScale < 1.0) {
        zoomScale = 1.0;
    }
}

- (void)setOffset:(CGPoint)o
{
    //This function is to make sure we don't pan outside the content range
    //it needs some work, I'm having trouble getting the panning to work
    float size = m.cellSize * zoomScale;
    offset = o;
    if ((offset.x - self.frame.size.width/size) <= 0) {
        //offset.x = self.frame.size.width;
        NSLog(@"X MIN");
    }
    if ((offset.x + self.frame.size.width/size) >= (m.gridLength*size)) {
       // offset.x = (m.gridLength*size) - self.frame.size.width;
        NSLog(@"X MAX");
    }
    if ((offset.y - self.frame.size.height/size) <= 0) {
        //offset.y = self.frame.size.height;
        NSLog(@"Y MIN");
    }
    if ((offset.y + self.frame.size.height/size) >= (m.gridLength*size)) {
       // offset.y = (m.gridHeight*size) - self.frame.size.height;
        NSLog(@"Y MAX");
    }
}

- (BOOL)checkCellAt:(float)x
               andY:(float)y
{
    int X = (int)(x/m.cellSize * zoomScale);
    int Y = (int)(y/m.cellSize * zoomScale);

    return [m cellAtX:X andY:Y];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);

    float size = m.cellSize * zoomScale;
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];

    float a = offset.x;
    float b = offset.y;

    //the -5 is there to give a little buffer so that half cells can be seen
    // -a is taken because the offset is negative
    int startX = (int)(-a/size) - 5;
    int startY = (int)(-b/size) - 5;

    int endX = (int)(startX) + (int)(rect.size.width/size) + 10;
    int endY = (int)(startY) + (int)(rect.size.height/size) + 10;

    if (startX < 0)
        startX = 0;
    if (startY < 0)
        startY = 0;
    if (endX > m.gridLength)
        endX = m.gridLength;
    if (endY > m.gridHeight)
        endY = m.gridHeight;

    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];

    for (float i=startX; i<endX; ++i) {
        for (float j=startX; j<endY; ++j) {
            if ([m cellAtX:(int)i andY:(int)j]) {
                //ii and jj are there to make the drawing start on the top left corner of the view
                float ii = i - startX;
                float jj = j - startY;
                CGRect cell = CGRectMake(size*ii, size*jj, size, size);
                CGContextFillRect(ctx, cell);
            }
        }
    }
}
@end
```

#### ZoomViewController.h

This view controller contains the gesture recognizers and handlers

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ZoomModel.h"
#import "ZoomView.h"

@interface ZoomViewController : UIViewController  <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    ZoomModel *m;
    ZoomView *v;
}

- (void)handleZoom:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;

@end
```

#### ZoomViewController.m

The zoomView is set inside a UIView which has the screen frame as its frame. The zoomView itself is made a little bit larger than the screen as to allow half cells to be drawn.

```
#import "ZoomViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation ZoomViewController

- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];

    float cellSize = 1;
    int ni = (int)(screenRect.size.width/cellSize);
    int nj = (int)(screenRect.size.height/cellSize);

    CGRect zoomRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1.2*screenRect.size.width, 1.2*screenRect.size.height);

    m = [[ZoomModel alloc] initWithLength:ni andHeight:nj andCellSize:cellSize];
    v = [[ZoomView alloc] initWithFrame:zoomRect andModel:m];
    v.center = CGPointMake(v.frame.size.width/2.0, v.frame.size.height/2.0);

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *zRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                      action:@selector(handleZoom:)];
    zRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [v addGestureRecognizer:zRecognizer];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                  action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [pRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [pRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];

    pRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [v addGestureRecognizer:pRecognizer];

    [mainView addSubview:v];

    [self setView:mainView];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer 
{        
    return YES;
}

- (void)handleZoom:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [v setZoomScale:recognizer.scale];

    //need code to zoom around the center instead of the top left corner
    recognizer.scale = 1;
    [v setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    //Adjusts the offset of the view, which is used in its drawRect:
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(v.offset.x - translation.x, v.offset.y - translation.y);
    [v setOffset:newOffset];
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
    [v setNeedsDisplay];
}
@end
```

#### ZoomModel.h

This class just populates a matrix of bools with random ON/OFF values, just so we can see something on the screen It simulates my more complex app model in its accessor method.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ZoomModel : NSObject
{
    bool *grid;
}

@property (nonatomic) int gridLength;
@property (nonatomic) int gridHeight;
@property (nonatomic) float cellSize;

- (id)initWithLength:(int)l
           andHeight:(int)h
         andCellSize:(float)s;

- (BOOL)cellAtX:(int)x
           andY:(int)y;
@end
```

#### ZoomModel.m

```
#import "ZoomModel.h"

@implementation ZoomModel
@synthesize gridHeight, gridLength, cellSize;

- (id)initWithLength:(int)l
           andHeight:(int)h
         andCellSize:(float)s
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        grid = malloc(l*h*sizeof(bool));
        gridHeight = h;
        gridLength = l;
        cellSize = s;

        for (int i=0; i<h*l; i++) {
            if (arc4random()%6 >= 4)
                grid[i] = true;
            else 
                grid[i] = false;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)cellAtX:(int)x andY:(int)y
{
    return (BOOL)grid[x*gridLength + y];
}
@end
```